# Why is AP Isolation not a standard feature for Ethernet?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, wireless-access-point

[AP Isolation](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Advanced_wireless_settings#AP_Isolation) is becoming a more common feature amongst the default firmware on many consumer-level routers. This feature makes it so wireless clients can't interact in any way with other wireless clients.

However, nowhere have I seen the similar logic being applied to Ethernet clients connected to the same router.

It could probably be done with Ethernet by making tons of VLANs and such, but is there any reason why this isn't a common built-in feature? You should trust whoever is connecting via Ethernet, sure, but isolation is still nice. :)

Comment: It is *very* easy with infrastructure mode (star topology). but *impossible* with Ethernet (any topology). It could be realized with additions to Ethernet, like VLANs.

Comment: You are wrong if you think "This feature makes it so wireless clients can't interact in any way with other wireless clients.". Check this thread: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16751/wireless-client-isolation-how-does-it-work-and-can-it-be-bypassed

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you seem to have missed Private VLANs. Devices in a private VLAN cannot communicate with other devices on the same VLAN.

One problem is that switching is done mostly in hardware, which is now a commodity and cheap. Adding features such as Private VLANs requires more expensive changes to the switch software. This is a common feature of business-grade switches.